# How to change themes in bootsfaces

Tags: bootsfaces

I've create webapp application with BootsFaces. Now I want change the themes used currently. I've cloned the git repository and tried to change themes by downloading a theme from bootswatch as per the documentation provided below.

> Customization
>
> Until there is a new version of the customizer, you can still
>   customize the look and feel taking advantage of the build system.
>   There are many Bootstrap customizers on the net, for example
>   Bootswatch . What you need is a file with the variables to customize
>   the build. Some customizers will provide you a .less file as well.
>
> Put the files in the BootsFaces/less directory of the build and tweak
>   the bs-* files to use your variables / .less file.

Bootswatch I can download variables.less, bootswatch.less, but in bootsfaces there files such as alerts.less, badges.less, bsf.less. I'm not sure how to customize the themes. I'm completely lost trying to changes themes.

**UPDATE**

That's exactly the problem; from bootswatch or for that matter from any Bootstrap site I would get boots `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.css`, however in the bootsfaces source code I find `bsf.css` and `theme.css` file in directory `BootsFaces-OSP-master\BootsFaces\css`. And `theme.css` in `BootsFaces-OSP-master\BootsFaces-OSP-master\BootsFaces\themes` directory and `BootsFaces.css` in `BootsFaces-OSP-master\BootsFaces\min` directory which on do I need to replace with `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: You'll have to compile the *.less files to *.css files. But I suppose there's a simpler way: Bootswatch also allows you to download the CSS file directly (at least in the one example I checked).

Comment: @StephanRauh can please explain bit more, how to compile *.less to *.css, in the git source code I find both .less and *.css files

Comment: First of all, I hope you don't need to compile the LESS files because there is already a set of pre-compiled CSS files. But if you need to, or if you want to, have a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt and here: http://lesscss.org/. You'll have to install node.js and Grunt. That's a matter of 30 minutes (unless you start thinking instead of following the instructions word-by-word :)).

Comment: updated question for better readablilty

Comment: The BootsFaces default theme is the `theme.css` file. You have to activate it manually in the web.xml to use it. So in theory it should suffice to include the bootstrap.min.css manually to each JSF page. Alternatively, you can include the bootstrap.css file - it's slower, but can be read by humans (i.e. you :)).

Comment: As for the files in the min folder of BootsFaces: they contain the CSS and JS code needed to run the widgets, but without the theme. So, in your context, you can safely ignore them.

Comment: I've just been told that changing the BootsFaces theme is more complicated than adding the Bootstrap.min.css file. But I'm also told that it is possible indeed. More details are soon to follow (probably not by me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Karthik
BootsFaces Team is still working on getting Bootswatch Themes in the Build, so we can obtain BootsFaces library in many flavours.

Of course it is not so easy and actually requires building the library after some changes are made, here is how:

1. After cloning the github repository, download bootswatch.less and variables.less of your favorite theme
2. rename variables.less to bs-variables.less and copy it with bootswatch.less in the less directory
3. edit bs-core.less to import the bs-variables.less file in order to override the original variables

   ```
   // Core variables
   @import "variables.less";
   // Custom Variables override
   @import "bs-variables.less";
   ```
4. edit bs-theme.less to import bs-variables.less and bootswatch.less to override original variables and apply changes to the the theme

   ```
   // Core variables
   @import "variables.less";
   @import "bs-variables.less";

   @import "theme.less";
   @import "bootswatch.less";
   ```
5. depending on the bootswatch theme customisations, other files might need the changes you made in step 3, e.g. bs-alert
6. now build the library using Gradle (read Gradle build requirements) and enjoy!

Comment: yes, I would follow this step rather than adding bootstrap.min.css as I find duplicate themes are copied.......

Comment: Update: v0.8.0 added Bootswatch Themes support [see Themes section](http://www.bootsfaces.net/layout/themes.jsf)

Answer (score 0):

You can the give the `link` an id and on a specific event change the `href` attribute to the css file you want.

Example:

**HTML**

```
// Inside head of document
<link id="currentCSS" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">


<select id="cssSelector" class="form-control">
    <option value="https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">Cerulean</option>
    <option value="https://bootswatch.com/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">Cosmo</option>
    <option value="https://bootswatch.com/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css">Cyborg</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('#cssSelector').on('change', function(event) {
        var css = $(this).val();
        $('#currentCSS').attr('href', css);
    });
});
```